# Jquery ajax chat - Messages doesn't automatic reload every 2 seconds?

Tags: jquery

I have set a timeout every 2 seconds to reload the content.
When I load the page, it loads the messages fine after 2 seconds, but then it doesn't do anything, unless I refresh the page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("ajax.php", { login : $("#guest").val() }, function(data) {
            location.reload();
        });
    });
});
setTimeout(function() {
    reload();
}, 2000);   


function reload() {
    $.post("ajax.php", { loadMessages : "1" }, function(data) {
        $("#loading").show();
        $("#box").html(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
```

**What did I do wrong?
I remember using timeouts, it always was repeating itself?**

Comment: sending an ajax request every two seconds is not a great idea

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` only runs once, use `setInterval` to have it constantly called every 2 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    reload();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, I figured it out exactly few seconds after I posted the question. I always got confused between these two. Finally I know the difference now. thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it :)